# Error de argumento 0 pero espera 1 dart, (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart

Buenas tengo en este código dos errores, uno que por argumento pues espera 1 y tengo 0 y otro de sintáis, no doy con la solución, os adjunto el código.

```
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    BoxData? newBoxData;
    if (boxDataSelect != null) {
      setState(() {
        listBoxData = storage.listBoxDataSort;
        //newBoxData = boxDataSelect!;
        newBoxData = boxDataSelect!.copyWith(
          fecha: boxDataSelect!.fecha,
          preciosHora: boxDataSelect!.preciosHora,
          mapRenovables: boxDataSelect!.mapRenovables,
          mapNoRenovables: boxDataSelect!.mapNoRenovables,
        );
      });
    }

    Widget mainBody = MainBodyEmpty(tokenSaved: sharedPrefs.token);
    if (httpStatus == HttpStatus.started ||
        httpStatus == HttpStatus.api ||
        httpStatus == HttpStatus.file ||
        httpStatus == HttpStatus.generacion) {
      mainBody = MainBodyStarted(stringProgress: httpStatus.textProgress);
    } 
    else if (httpStatus == HttpStatus.completed &&
        listBoxData.isNotEmpty &&
        listBoxData.isNotEmpty &&
        newBoxData != null) {
          mainBody = SizedBox(
            width: double.infinity,
            height: double.infinity,
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
              controller: scrollController,
              child: (() {
                if (currentTab == 0) {
                  return HomeTab(boxData: newBoxData!);
                  } 
                else if (currentTab == 1 || currentTab == 2) {
                  return PreciosTab(tab: currentTab, boxData: newBoxData!);
                  } 
                else if (currentTab == 3) {
                  return TimelapseTab(boxData: newBoxData!);
                  } 
                else {
                  return HomeTab(boxData: newBoxData!);
                  }
                })
                (),
                0 => HomeTab(boxData: newBoxData!), //AQUI ME ESTA DANDO ERROR
                /*Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found.
                Try removing the extra positional arguments, or specifying the name for named arguments.
Expected to find ')'.*/


                1 => PreciosTab(
                  tab: currentTab,
                  boxData: newBoxData!,
                ),
                2 => PreciosTab(
                  tab: currentTab,
                  boxData: newBoxData!,
                ),
                3 => TimelapseTab(boxData: newBoxData!),
                int() => HomeTab(boxData: newBoxData!),
                  
          },
        ),
      );
    }
```

Bien en definitiva esto son los errores traducidos, no doy con la clave.
Demasiados argumentos posicionales: se esperaba 0, pero se encontró 1.
Intente eliminar los argumentos posicionales adicionales o especificar el nombre de los argumentos con nombre.
Se esperaba encontrar ')'.

Comment: El mensaje de error está siendo bastante descriptivo: ¿por qué le estás pasando argumentos posicionales a algo que no recibe argumentos de ese tipo? Encima te está diciendo claramente el mensaje: _Intenta eliminar los argumentos posicionales adicionales o especifica el nombre de los argumentos con nombre._

Comment: Correto, lo solucioné ayer quitando el trozo de código, optimizándolo de otra manera. Gracias por tu información

Answer (score 0):

La solución paso por quitar parte del código y optimizando el mismo.

Comment: Esto no proporciona una respuesta a la pregunta. Para criticar o pedir aclaración a un autor, deja un comentario debajo de su publicación. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/399107)